# Converting string to data

Tags: android, time

I am getting a duration of my audio file , convert it to int , then convert int to string and then string to something like this 00:32 . Converted string is correct, but then is a problem with convert that string to data

Here is my code:

```
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyImages/.audio1.wav");
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            FileInputStream fs = null;
            FileDescriptor fd = null;
            try {
                fs = new FileInputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fd = fs.getFD();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(fd);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            int length = mp.getDuration()/1000;
            mp.release();

            String audiotime = String.valueOf(length);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mmss");
            try {
              Date d = sdf.parse(audiotime);
              textView1.setText(audiotime);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {

            }
```

Comment: Maybe ParseException is throw but you ignore it... log it

Comment: cant coz i am using my sdcard when getting file time, so my device is not connected

Comment: save it in a file then read it? a toast?

Answer (score 0):

Two things, most important, you use the original String as text for your `TextView`. You should do something like `textView1.setText(d.toString());`

Secondly, you should use "mm:ss" as your format, instead of "mmss".

Note you could also use the `format` function of `SimpleDateFormat`. This will return a `StringBuffer`, which might be more appropriate since you only need the `String` representation

source: [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)